# Multiple columns instead of rows - PDO statement

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, rows

I'm trying to display data of a certain table over 3 columns and want it to continue to the next row after 3 results, so if there's 30 results there should be 10 rows of 3 columns, if there's 15 results there should be 5 rows of 3 columns etc.

However I can only find examples on how to do this with "normal sql statements" and couldn't find anything in PDO that can do the same, and unfortunatly mixing normal SQL and PDO doesn't work well.

Well here is my code:

```
$result = getdatanames($db, $_GET['id']);
foreach ($result as $row) {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td style="width: 20%; text-align:right;"><a href="/?p=USERS.profile&amp;id='.$row->idd.'">'.$row->name.'</a></td>';
  echo '<td style="width: 13%;"><span style="font-variant:small-caps;font-size:10px;position:relative;top:-5px;color:#C11B17;">'.$row->last_name.'</span></td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
```

However I know this is going to display per row(Both first name and last name), but how can I make it work so 3 records display per row(both first name and last name)?

Aka:

```
  Name Last name - Name Last name - Name Last name
  Name Last name - Name Last name - Name Last name
  Name Last name - Name Last name - (Empty auto fill)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has got nothing to do with `PDO` or `mysql`, you just need to add a counter and only add a `</tr><tr>` block whenever you can divide your counter through 3. Or add a column variable and set it to 1 after it has hit 3.

And perhaps add a few columns after the loop to complete your last row.

With a column counter:

```
$column = 0;
echo '<tr>';
foreach ($result as $row)
{
  $column++;
  echo '<td style="width: 20%; text-align:right;"><a href="/?p=USERS.profile&amp;id='.$row->idd.'">'.$row->name.'</a></td>';
  echo '<td style="width: 13%;"><span style="font-variant:small-caps;font-size:10px;position:relative;top:-5px;color:#C11B17;">'.$row->last_name.'</span></td>';
  if ($column == 3)
  {
    $column = 0;
    echo '</tr><tr>';
  }
}
echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: Hello there, I know it has not, but the counter ways I could find online in tutorials were in "plain/normal" sql, which doesn't work well with PDO hence why I removed them I couldn't get them to work.

I know the current piece of code I have wont work in the way I want it to and has to be changed, I"m just showing how it is now, and how I would want it to be

Comment: @Bauke Van der Meer I have added a code example (without the part to complete the row at the end).

Comment: Works like a charm, thank a bunch for the quick solution been looking for hours!